# how to edit a specific element of an array on user's action

Tags: angularjs

I have an array of objects which I am databinding -

```
$scope.records = [
    {field: "Full Name", value: "Joe Hanigan", isVisible: true},
    {field: "Age", value: "52 Years", isVisible: true},
    {field: "Diagnosis", value: "Common Cold", isVisible: true},
    {field: "Hospital Elum", value: "Alpha Lopus Epsum", isVisible: false},
    {field: "Hospital Code", value: "CKD34-23", isVisible: false}
  ];
```

I am just displaying 'field' and 'isVisible' as a check box. I want to toggle the value of 'isVisisble' when a user checks/unchecks, the box in the browser.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you use your array in a `ng-repeat`, where you will define an input field of type checkbox. You use `ng-model` to bind the field to the model:

```
<div ng-repeat="record in records">
   <input type="checkbox" name="isVisible" ng-model="record.isVisible">
</div>
```

Comment: +1 for the answer. However I would like to run some logic when the change is made, maybe make some server side changes, do some validations, how do I do that? In this case I would like to update it on the server. And the model will be retrieved from an angular service.